# Selecting a start value for a Slider without triggering ValueChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I want to set the slider Value to 10 and then make it possible to move it down or up again, but when I set a Value for the slider, I get an Error which says

[System.NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKDhu.png)

this is the code:

```
        <MenuItem Header = "Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Transparence">
                <Slider Width="100" Name="transparence" ValueChanged="transparenz_ValueChanged" 
                        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Value="10"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

this is the method where the exception occures

```
    private void transparenz_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Input.Opacity = transparenz.Value * 0.1;
    }
```

when I remove the value from the XAML File, everything works fine

I just want to have this Slider start at the end

[The Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNJ5a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to happen **before** having its event handlers attached, you need to set it in your constructor in code behind instead of XAML, like this:

In your MainWindow.xaml.cs (or whatever your view is named .xaml.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        transparenz.Value = 10;
    }
    ... Rest of your code here
}
```

Then remove `Value="10"` from your XAML file.

Comment: thank you! I changed to code to this and now it works, idk why but it doesnt work if I put the Value above the InitializeComponent() but it does if I put it under it


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            transparenz.Value = 10;
        }

Comment: My bad, InitializeComponent is also setting the `transparenz` instance. I will correct the answer. If it helped you, you can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The name is wrong... change for Name="transparenz"

```
 <Slider Width="100" Name="transparenz" ValueChanged="transparenz_ValueChanged" 
                            IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Value="10"/>

private void transparenz_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            Input.Opacity = transparenz.Value * 0.1;
        }
```

Comment: The name is absolutely unrelated to the subscription mechanism.